# How can I encrypt or obfuscate Flask code?

Tags: flask

For safety reasons, is there any way to protect flask app code?

I have tried to compile a `.py` into a `.pyc`, but the web app won't run.

I have also tried to use a [python confuse tool](http://pyob.oxyry.com/), but the effect is not ideal.

Whether the flask application can be packaged by pyinstaller or cptyhon.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  I expect that you mean you have a Flask app running on a live server, connected to the web.  How are you hosting it?  Is it on a Linux server running something like Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Basically no, its pretty trivial to decompile python bytecode. Set up the server properly to prevent serving your code.

Comment: The flask web app running environment : Linux + nginx + uWSGI + flask.

Comment: There are a lot of people have root privilege, what can I do is to find ways to prevent other people modify the code.Thank you very much!!!